# Saving state of button in Javascript even after refreshing for each logged-in user

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am working on a Django application and am trying to save the state of a button clicked.

I have a login form that accepts a registered user's credentials (if inputted). If successful, the user will be redirected to a page that'll contain two buttons. My main intention is to set 'button 1' and disable 'button 2' for a new user (once he/she logs in). So, if a user clicks on 'button 1', this button will get disabled and then 'button 2' will be enabled. When the same user logs out, the button state should be saved. This means that the user shouldn't click on 'button 1' again because 'button 2' was enabled last time.

However, this seems to be applied to all users who log in. The state of the button does not correspond with that particular user who's logged in but gets impacted to all users' in general.

This is the code:

**interface.html:**

```
<script>
    var disbledBtn = localStorage.getItem('disabled'); // get the id from localStorage
    $(disbledBtn).attr("disabled", true); // set the attribute by the id
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $("#button1").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#button2").attr("disabled", false);
        localStorage.setItem('disabled', '#button1');
    }
</script>

<body>
        <button type="button" id ='button1'>  Button 1 </button>
        <button type="button" id ='button2'> Button 2 </button>
</body>
```

**How do I keep User A's button state and User B's button state different from each other?**. Currently, if button1 was clicked in User A's account, then User B's button 2 will be enabled (which is not what I want)

Is there a way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Save unique localStorage item for each user and store it with there _id (`localStorage.getItem(_id);`) instead of localStorage.getItem('disabled');

Comment: I will suggest you to save the user state in database. The `localstorage` is created per browser/machine i.e. one user logins from 1st machine and sets the state and then login again from 2nd machine then original state will be loaded not the saved state.

Comment: @BrijeshGajera Can you give a small demonstration, please?

Comment: @anuragal So the state will have a One-to-One relationship with a user, correct? How do I store it in my model? Can you present a small example? I would highly appreciate that.

Comment: Please follow this article to learn about models and database - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Localstorage**

```
Key         Value
1001        2
1002        1
1003        2
```

**Script**

```
<script>
        var user_id = 1001;  // unique id of user so we can find from localstorage

        var disbledBtn = localStorage.getItem(user_id);  // here it gives 1 OR 2 (if 1 then button1 is desabled, if 2 then button2 is disabled 

        if(disbledBtn == 2) {
          $("#button2").attr("disabled", true);  // disable button2  
        } else {
          $("#button1").attr("disabled", true);  // disable button1
        }

        $('#button1').click(function () {
            $("#button1").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#button2").attr("disabled", false);
            localStorage.setItem(user_id, '1');    // store 1 in localstorage because button1 is now disabled
        }
        $('#button2').click(function () {
            $("#button2").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#button1").attr("disabled", false);
            localStorage.setItem(user_id, '2');    // store 2 in localstorage because button2 is now disabled
        }

    </script>

    <body>
        <button type="button" id ='button1'>  Button 1 </button>
        <button type="button" id ='button2'> Button 2 </button>
    </body>
```

Comment: if suppose there were a lot of users, would the application slow down (due to using up the localStorage space)?

Comment: Also, user_Id is hardcoded now, is there a way to dynamically tell JS which user is who? Or should I use django models to store the value?

Comment: i think localstorage is new for you so **localstorage** is store in local memory(not on server or database) its in users browser you can see it in `developer tool(ctrl + sift + d) -> Application -> Storage -> Local Storage`  [Localstorage](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/) 

it cant affect speed

Comment: Oh okay, what about the second question I asked? Right now, the user_id is hardcoded to 1001, how can I change this and dynamically tell JS which user is who via user_id?

Comment: localstorage is store in browser so when you create localstorage for user1, user2, and user3 it store in there computers  user1 contain only his/her localstorage not others

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to hear me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace LocalStorage via https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Cookies fully different for each user.

Comment: I will give this a try but I want to implement Brijesh's idea for now. Thank you so much for the suggestion though.